# MVC Dropdownlist not selecting default value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have searched alot for this problem, and have seen many fixes, but none seemed to work for me.
I want to set a default value for a `dropdownlist` because when I want to edit a person, the **partner's dropdownlist** always goes to the default text `'select a partner'` and when I want to save changes to the person, I either have to remember what partner the person had and select him again, or the partner just changes to `null` in the database...

The code I have right now is :

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    // GET: /Persoon/Edit/5
    [Authorize(Roles = "Beheerder")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var persoon = _persoonBll.GetById(id);
        if (persoon == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var persoonViewModel = new PersoonDetailViewModel()
        {
            PersoonID = persoon.PersoonID,
            Voornaam = persoon.Voornaam,
            Naam = persoon.Naam,
            GSM = persoon.GSM,
            Email = persoon.Email,
            Telefoon = persoon.Telefoon,
            PartnerID = persoon.PartnerID

        };

        //generate list of partners
        var PossiblePartners= _persoonBll.GetPossiblePartnersForPersoon(persoon).ToList();


        //generate views for possible partners
        IEnumerable<SimplePersoonViewModel> simpleList = CreateSimplepPersoonForList(PossiblePartners);


        ViewBag.PossiblePartners= new SelectList(simpleList, "Id", "Fullname");


        ... more code
     }
```

Here is the code that makes the list:

```
    private IEnumerable<SimplePersoonViewModel>     CreateSimplepPersoonForList(List<Persoon> lstPersons)
    {

        var lstSimplePersons = new List<SimplePersoonViewModel>();
        lstPersons.ToList().ForEach(p => lstSimplePersons.Add(new SimplePersoonViewModel() { Id = p.PersoonID, Fullname = p.FullName }));
        return lstSimplePersons;
    }
```

simpleList is a list I created to fill up the `dropdownlist`. That works perfectly fine.

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="form-
       <p>
           <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Partner.FullName) %>
       </p>

       <%: Html.DropDownList("PartnerID",
              (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossiblePartners,
                          "--- Choose a partner ---",  
                                 new { @class="chosen-select"})%>

       <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartnerID) %>

   </div>
```

I have tried different things already, one of them is:

```
ViewBag.PossiblePartners= new SelectList(simpleList, "Id", "Fullname", persoon.PartnerId);
```

But whatever I do or try, the `dropdownlist` keeps showing the `'Choose a partner'`...

Comment: Yes, because my dropdownlist fills up the way it should, with all the _'partners'_...

Comment: what is `persoon` ? Does `persoon.PArtnerId` one of the Id from simpleList ?

Comment: You need to set the value of `PartnerID` in the controller before you pass the model to the view (model binding works by binding to the value of your property)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with ViewModel, and SelectListItem? I would do something like this

**Controller:**

```
Model.Partners = partnerList.Select(partner => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = partner.FullName,
    Value = partner.Id
}).ToList();
```

**HTML:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PartnerId, new SelectList(Model.Partners, "value", "text"), "--- Choose a partner ---", new { @class = "chosen-select"})
```

**PartnerId** should be *string*. And then you just need to set PartnerId.

Comment: Already tried this too, but same result.. The dropdownlist just selects the default message.

Comment: I updated my answer, try like that. Just don't forget to set  **PartnerId** @DenzelvanBelle

Answer (score -2):

The problem is at:

```
 ViewBag.PossiblePartners = new SelectList(simpleList, "Id", "Fullname");
```

There is a forth parameter that is the selected value, so, you have to pass the existent element Id to it. It's worth to mention that is the Id and not the entire object, as the selected property is based in the "Id". So, it would be something like this:

```
ViewBag.PossiblePartners = new SelectList(simpleList, "Id", "Fullname", selectedElement.Id);
```

You have said that you tried:

```
ViewBag.PossiblePartners= new SelectList(simpleList, "Id", "Fullname", persoon.PartnerId);
```

But you are using "Id" as the dataValueField and using "PartnerId" from the "persoon" object, what make me believe that the Id coming from "persoon.PartnerId" is not in the "simpleList" object. Please take a look at it to confirm.

I have tested it and it works just fine. Have a nice weekend. Regards.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Model binding works by binding to the value of the property. Setting the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when binding to a property and the only time it works is when using `@Html.DropDownList("NotAProperty", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossiblePartners, ....)`

Comment: You are right, it works when uses DropDownList and that is exactly what is being used in the question. And I have to complement saying that `@Html.DropDownList("NotAProperty", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossiblePartners, ....)` works with a Property as well. The programmer can choose if he wants to use DropDownList or DropDownListFor, though the syntax is different. When i said that I´ve tested I really did, as I just did using a property at `@Html.DropDownList("Property", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossiblePartners, ....)` and it just binded correctly. Regards.

Comment: In the simplelist I have the persoon.id & the persoon.fullname for every person in that simpleList. So when I try to set the default value to the current partnerId (partnerId = id of a different person in the database) it should work, because when I select someone in the dropdownlist and save it, it gets the id of the selected item and puts it in the database as the new partner (and that works perfectly fine).. But zholinho says the partnerId has to be a string, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: As you said, when you do a selection in the dropdownlist it gets to the server and you can save it, meaning that the problem is not at the binding when the request get at the server. May you provide the whole action code so we can see what is going on? The way I posted just works. The person that you want to bet se as the default value also must be at the simpleList. You may want to make a test, change your viewbag code to `... = new SelectList(simpleList, "Id", "Fullname", simpleList[1].Id);` the way you will select the first element of simple list depends of the object type it is. Regards.

Comment: I will update my post with some more code. And the simpleList[1].Id doesn't work as it is an <IEnumerable>SimplePersoonViewModel..

Comment: Can't edit my commet and accidently pressed Enter... I tried using simpleList.First() and still the **dropdownlist** selects nothing (just shows the default text).. Thanks for all of you time by the way :)

Comment: Have you tried `simpleList.First().Id` (can´t be the whole object but just the value that is being used as the value parameter, `Id` in this case)?